# Высокая контрасность в Chromium 58

Tags: google-chrome

Как исправить цвета в Chromium (см. картинку)?
Chromium version: 58.0.3019.0 (Developer Build). Ниже таже страница в Firefox.

[image: Version 58.0.3019.0 (Developer Build) (64-]bit)

Comment: Может стоит подождать официального билда Chrome? Или, в крайнем случае, отправить фидбэк разработчикам?

Comment: В ярлыке одного из браузеров посмотрите скорее всего стоит параметр `--enable-monitor-profile`, уберите его или добавьте к обоим, должно сработать.